# How to clone a message in outbox of outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have an email ready to be sent in Outbox. The one with configured with `delayed delivery` option.

I want to have the second cloned message of that message. How can I do that?

p.s.

I have an idea of hitting the `replying` button but then I have to set the `delayed delivery` option again. A quick google give me nowhere. So I ask here.

Comment: Why can't you just do a copy and paste operation on the email?  Use `right click=Copy` and the `ctrl+V` to copy and paste.

Comment: So you mean copying and pasting To, CC, subject, content, and the `delayed delivery` option. Wow, I don't think I would love my day full with that :(

Comment: No; you can copy the email itself then paste it; read my comment

Comment: I see. It works ^^ and sound so naive of me. Actually Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V will do and via right clicking do not.